# How do I split a short into its two bytes?

Tags: c#

I have to split up a *short* into its two bytes. They have to be in Network order.
I need that for a small server telling the current size of the rest packet's data.

```
List<byte> o = new List<byte>();
o.Add(0x03);
// here this short
o.AddRange(MapData);
o.Add(0xFF);
Send(o);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht0w88zx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  You can then use GetBytes or bit manipulation to access the actual bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx) method:

```
short someShortValue = 25;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(someShortValue);
```

Comment: That only gives you the bytes in network order if the system endianess happens to be the same as the network order.